# Zappa–Szép product vs. direct product

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $G$ a group. Let $\alpha:G\rightarrow{\rm Bij}(A)$ and $\beta: A\rightarrow{\rm Bij}(G)$ be two group homomorphisms. I have tried to prove that the Zappa–Szép product $A{}_{\alpha}{\bowtie}_{\beta} G$ is isomorphic to the direct product $A\times G$ iff $\alpha(g)=id$ and $\beta(a)=id$ for all $g\in G$ and $a\in A$.

The if direction is clear. For the converse, if $G$ is abelian then $A{}_{\alpha}{\bowtie}_{\beta} G$ is abelian and hence $\alpha(g)=id$ and $\beta(a)=id$. If $G$ is nonabelian, I think it is possible for a direct product $A\times G$ to be isomorphic to $A{}_{\alpha}{\bowtie}_{\beta} G$ with $\alpha $ and $\beta$ are both nontrivial, but I couldn't find a counter-example. So I will be thankful if someone provides me a counterexample. Notice that I have asked a similar question in [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452681/is-it-possible-for-a-direct-product-to-be-isomorphic-to-the-zappa-sz%c3%a9p-product).

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you let $A_5$ act on itself via conjugation and form the group $A_5\rtimes A_5$, you get a group that is isomorphic to $A_5\times A_5$. See, e.g., [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/166241/3959).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thank you very much. I see you restricted to semidirect products, but I want a counterexample on Zappa–Szép products in which the actions $\alpha $ and $\beta$ are both nontrivial.

Comment: And the example did not have one group abelian. It does, however, suggest that there is reason for doubt.

Comment: It's okay to [post also in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/452681/3959) after a while, but when you do you should note in both posts that the question is now posted on the other site. It's polite, and it prevents duplication of effort.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  Yes of course you are right. I add a notification to the questions. Thank you.

Comment: Why is $A\bowtie G$ abelian if $A$ and $G$ are both abelian? For example, the Klein bottle group $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ is non-abelian.

Comment: Also, it would help if you defined an antihomomorphism, and said what your motivation for this problem is.

Comment: @user1729 I used the  assumption  $A{}_{\alpha}{\bowtie}_{\beta} G\cong A\times G$ of the only if direction. Note that, since A is abelian, an anti-homomorphism is in fact a homomorphism.

Comment: Ah, ok. Also, you didn't address motivation. (This question is not particularly hard but with a minor twist becomes more complex, which is why I'm wondering.)

Comment: @user1729 In fact, I have seen similar questions concerning "the isomorphism between a semidirect product and a direct product" which give some interesting examples proving in some cases the isomorphism between semidirect products and direct product ( see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201710/is-there-a-nontrivial-semidirect-product-of-two-groups-isomorphic-to-their-direc)). Here, I hope finding similar examples for the Zappa-szép products.

Comment: @N.SNANOU Sure, but then Derek Holt's answer there gives you a counter-example to the question you asked here. You could also take semi-direct products $\mathbf{Z}\ltimes_{\phi}G$ for $\phi$ inner, etc.

Comment: (Here $\alpha$ is trivial and $\beta$ is not, so we obviously have a semidirect product. Your comment above and MO question implies you actually want $\alpha$ to be non-trivial?)